# Why didn't the executioners follow the rope to Buckbeak?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm currently reading the penultimate chapter of *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*  and I can only assume that my reading comprehension has completely failed me.

As I understand it, Buckbeak is tied to a fence by a rope and Harry has grabbed this rope and used it to drag Buckbeak in to the forest where they can't be seen. However, I can't see any references to this rope being untied or broken, so why didn't the executioners just follow the rope to their target?

The only relevant line that I can find is:

> "Harry began to fumble with the knot of rope tying Buckbeak to the fence"

but "fumble" is not a word that implies success. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably because the rope got untied or broken. I mean, you don't see any references to hippogriff feces either, doesn't mean there wasn't any.

Comment: But "fumble" doesn't, in this context, imply failure either.  It denotes doing something clumsily.

Answer (score 4):

Harry did manage to untie the rope or he broke the rope. Either way he saved Buckbeak.

It wouldn't be possible to get Buckbeak away without untying the rope, and I thought the reason was obvious: The rope wasn't long enough!

There is quite a distance between the Forest and Hagrid's Hut, and the rope wouldn't be long enough for that distance. So Harry must have broken or untied it.

When Buckbeak is found to have escaped, Hagrid says he "mustn't have tied him up properly", which implies that Harry untied the rope.

Comment: Hagrid's line, to me, implies that they untied the rope in some manner that looked natural, like Buckbeak had gotten away on his own. It wouldn't make sense to say that if the rope had been clearly cut through.

Comment: @Cadence They could've cut the rope in such a way that would look like he had bit the rope with his beak

Answer (score 3):

## Buckbeak’s rope was indeed untied.

Though Harry struggled with the rope, he did succeed in untying it. When the executioner found that Buckbeak was gone, he exclaimed that someone must have untied him.

> “Someone untied him!’ the executioner was snarling. ‘We should search the grounds, the Forest –’
>
> ‘Macnair, if Buckbeak has indeed been stolen, do you really think the thief will have led him away on foot?’ said Dumbledore, still sounding amused. ‘Search the skies, if you will … Hagrid, I could do with a cup of tea.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 21 (Hermione’s Secret)*</sup></sub>

The executioner specifically says the rope was untied, so there would have been no rope to follow, and Dumbledore quickly dismissed the idea of searching the ground for Buckbeak.